# Trouble Passing Json Object As Parameter

Tags: jquery, json, object, parameters

I am not able to successfully pass a JSON object as a parameter, i get an uncaught referenceError..any ideas?

```
$.getJSON('./getMe.php', function(data){
    $.each(data, function(key, pack){
        var id = key.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");
        $('#breadcrumbs').append("&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id='" + id + " 'onclick='DoSomething(id, pack);'>" + key + "</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    });

    $('#breadcrumbs').append('</br></br>'); })
    .success(function(){
        $('#loader').hide();
});

function DoSomething(id, pack){
    $.each(pack, function(stage, items){
        alert(stage);
    });
    $('#packages').html('&rarr;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + id);
}
```

Im trying to pass `pack` to `DoSomething()`

Comment: You are not passing `pack` as variable. Pass it like you passed `id` of `span`

Comment: But, doing that will try to output the variable as text, instead of as the JSON object.

Comment: I tried that as well and it was not working either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to pass it in a variable like that, which is why your are getting the reference error. Here is what you can do:

```
data = [{test: "test", hi: "hi!"}]

$.each(data, function(key, pack){
    var id = key,
        clickLink = $('<span>' + key + '</span>')
             .attr({id: id})
             .click(function() { doSomething(id, pack);});

    $('#breadcrumbs').append(clickLink);
});

var doSomething = function(id, pack) {
    alert(pack);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

here is an example you might find useful http://momotaroblogger.blogspot.co.nz/2012/11/webapi.html